Android foreground service in MAUI Blazor .net8
I'm developing an application on MAUI Blazor .net8 for monitoring purposes. For periodic sending of phone coordinates on Android, now I'm using the shiny.net library. The application works. The coordinates are sent from the foreground service, however, if I close the application, the foreground service also stops working.
To start working, I watched Gerald Versluis' videos "Track Users Location in the Background with Android and Xamarin.Forms" (https://youtu.be/Q_renpfnbk4) - in this video, Gerald closes the application (https://youtu.be/Q_renpfnbk4?t=1904) and the foreground service still works. I need exactly this behavior, but I couldn't implement Gerald's example on .net8, so I switched to shiny.net.
I followed the instructions on the website (https://shinylib.net/client/locations/gps/). The application works. The coordinates are sent from the foreground service, however, if I close the application, the foreground service also stops working. Is it possible to make the foreground service continue working even when the application is closed, and show the user a notification, clicking on which, they could restart the main application? Can I use shiny.net for this?
I'm running it on Android 14, for this I specified all the necessary permissions in the manifest, including android:foregroundServiceType="location".

How did you close the app? Double click the exit button or close it in the recent task? If you closed it in the recent task, the foreground service will also be closed. Because that action will kill the application process.

Thank you very much for paying attention to the issue. Yes, to close the application, I use the 'close it in the recent task' method. However, Gerald does the same in his video (https://youtu.be/Q_renpfnbk4?t=1904s) and the foreground service continues to work. I'm trying to understand if this is standard behavior or if it can be done with some kind of hack?

I have checked the video. It's strange the debuggger still run when he removed the app from the recent task. Actually, the foreground service will stop when the aplication process is killed. The emulator in the video seems used low android version. In addition, you may try the android:process to make the foreground service run in different process.
